# onBeforeEnter does not exist in vue-router@next

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I am trying to switch over to vuejs3 and the new vue-router.

Now I see that beforeRouteEnter is not exposed:

```
 // same as beforeRouteUpdate option with no access to `this`
        onBeforeRouteUpdate((to, from, next) => {
            // your logic
            console.log("Hello world") //this is only triggered if the id changes
            next()
        })
```

So my question is: How can I trigger the initial axios-requests on a specific route like `/dashboard` as I did before?

Comment: Did you check these?
https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#navigation-guards

Comment: Hi RajkumarG, yes, I did. And I did not see a method that applies as beforeRouteEnter-guard within the setup-method. Maybe this is not a concept here?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to execute code in `setup` before the route enters because at the time of `setup` the navigation has already been confirmed.

**Another option #1**

You can still use the options api, so you could still use `beforeRouteEnter`:

```
setup() {
  ...
},
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  console.log(to);
}
```

**Another option #2**

Use `beforeEnter` in the router:

```
{
  path: '/foo',
  component: Foo,
  beforeEnter(to) {
    console.log(to)
  }
}
```